# Por que no me funciona este arreglo tipo string con objetos c++?

Tags: c++, array, string

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Persona
{
private:
    string Nombre;
public:
    double sumaVentas, Venta;
    string setNombre(string);
    string getNombre();
    void ObtenerVenta();
    double PromedioVendedor();
};

string Persona::setNombre(string elnombre)
{

    Nombre = elnombre;
}

string Persona::getNombre()
{
    return Nombre;
}

void Persona::ObtenerVenta()
{
    sumaVentas=0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {        
        cout<<"Digite venta del mes "<<i+1<<endl;
        cin >> Venta;
        sumaVentas += Venta;
    }
}

double Persona::PromedioVendedor()
{
    return sumaVentas/4;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    string elnombre;

    cout << "Cuantos vendedores hay en la empresa? "<< endl;
    cin>>x;

    Persona ventas[x];
    Persona vendedor[x];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        cout << "Digite el nombre del vendedor " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin>>elnombre;
        vendedor[i].setNombre(elnombre);
        ventas[i].ObtenerVenta();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        cout << "Vendedor " << vendedor[i].getNombre()<< endl;
        cout << "El promedio es " << ventas[i].PromedioVendedor() << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

El problema es que cuando lo ejecuto, me funciona solo cuando asigno el nombre de un vendedor. Pero lo ejecuto para 2 o mas vendedores el arreglo objeto "Persona vendedor[x]" da error, haciendo que se quede pegado cuando pide el nombre del segundo vendedor. ¿Por que el arreglo objeto "Persona vendedor[x]" da ese tipo de error? si se supone que tiene que almacenar n catidad de nombres segun el usuario digite. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Estas creando un array en tiempo de ejecución porque el resultado del cin no se conoce hasta que se ejecute el programa, ese el problema. Si quieres hacer eso puedes guardar las ventas y vendedores en memoria dinamica: Persona* vendedor = new Persona[x];

Comment: Gracias, pero me piden resolver el ejercicio con memoria aumatica!. Pero tendre en cuenta tu observacion para futuras practicas.

Answer (score 1):

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) las formaciones<sup>1</sup> en memoria automática<sup>2</sup> se deben definir con un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación. En tu caso estás usando una variable como tamaño, por lo que su valor sólo se conoce en tiempo de ejecución.

Cambia tu formación por un `std::vector` y ya no tendrás ese problema:

```
int vendedores; // Usa nombres autoexplicativos
cout << "Cuantos vendedores hay en la empresa? "<< endl;
cin >> vendedores;

std::vector<Persona> ventas(vendedores);   // Vector de 'vendedores' elementos
std::vector<Persona> vendedor(vendedores); // Vector de 'vendedores' elementos

// Usa el for de rango para más comodidad
for (auto &v : vendedor)
{
    cout << "Digite el nombre del vendedor\n";
    // Declara las variables donde las vayas a usar
    string nombre;
    cin >> nombre;
    v.setNombre(nombre);
    v.ObtenerVenta();
}

for (int indice = 0; i != vendedores; ++indice)
{
    cout << "Vendedor " << vendedor[indice].getNombre()<< endl;
    cout << "El promedio es " << ventas[indice].PromedioVendedor() << endl;
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta

- Las cabeceras `<stdlib.h>` y `<string.h>` son de [c](/questions/tagged/c) y no deben ser usadas en C++.
- La cabecera que añade el tipo `std::string` es `<string>`, debes incluir esa.
- La cabecera que añade los objetos `std::cin` y `std::cout` es `<iostream>`, debes incluir esa.
- No estás usando la cabecera `<cstdlib>`, no deberías incluirla.
- La cabecera `<cstdlib>` es la versión portada a C++ de `<stdlib.h>`, estás incluyendo dos versiones de la misma cabecera (que ni siquiera estás usando).

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

<sup>2</sup>La memoria automática es aquella que no se pide con `new`.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono!. Pero tuve que incluir la cabecera include<vector> y usar un for clasico para que me funcionase!. Aprendi cosas nuevas gracias a tus comentario tan detallado.